# Assigning polygons to a feature class

Tags: point-in-polygon

I understand there’s a way or a program that can assign polygons (precincts) to a feature point.(Vote Centers)

For insistence the law states we need to assign a maximum of 10 precincts (or polygons) to a Vote Center. We have 607 precincts and 69 Vote Centers.

I utilized the "join" but it in some instances it assigned more than 10 polygons(precincts) per point(Vote Center)
Where do I set parameters (minimum or maximums)?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Desktop?  Have you looked at the Near tool?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the GIS software in use (including version) and provide more information about the exact process you have used.